# Show hidden images on website

Tags: javascript, php

How to see hidden images on this javascript game. This is timing memory game, and uses javascript to hide images after 2 clicks. Is there any extension or any way in console to edit the script to not hide images.
https://apps.pixel.mk/kviz-bimilk/memorija.php

Comment: Have you tried using firebug or chrome inspector?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Engjull! Unfortunately your question is too broad for this site. Also it as nothing to do with php. Please see “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)” for more information.

Comment: Yes @Arno, i have changed sourcecode to visible but javascript return it to hidden after clicking on another picture. Is there any extension who force chrome to show all hidden pictures, or to display the url of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or via javascript:

```
$('.card > img').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Yes but this is not my website, i can't edit the code, i just want to see hidden images on my browser :$ , in one way, i want to hack the game :D

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question: How to see hidden images on this javascript game.

Add this css, it should show all images:

```
img{
    visibility:visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Yes but this is not my website, i can't edit the code, i just want to see hidden images on my browser :$ , in one way, i want to hack the game :D

Comment: You can edit css in browser, go to Source tab inside devtools in chrome and find css file there